# Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions, while configuring the webpack

Tags: webpack-config

I am trying to configure webpack and babel from scratch. I am getting the following error. Can anyone help? I have attached the package.json screenshot.

Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions.

[image: Image of package.json]

Can any one see, if i am missing anything?